# Thrift: "->" operator giving me a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, thrift

EDIT: juan.facorro pointed me to the real issue, which is that when the server isn't running, `mytransport->open()` calls `GlobalOutput.perror("error code")` in TSocket.cpp. But in my code, `mytransport->open()` was called before `GlobalOutput` was initialized

see [this link](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.thrift.devel/1395) for more info

---

I have a `shared_ptr` called `mytransport`, and I declare it like so:

```
shared_ptr<TTransport> mytransport(new TBufferedTransport(socket));
```

but when I call `mytransport->open();` I get a segmentation fault, and the top of the stack trace says:

```
#0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x08068281 in apache::thrift::TOutput::perror (this=0x807a44c, message=0x9dc0e14 "TSocket::open() connect() <Host: localhost Port: 9090>", errno_copy=111) at src/thrift/Thrift.cpp:65
#2  0x080670eb in perror (errno_copy=<optimized out>, message=..., this=<optimized out>) at ./src/thrift/Thrift.h:123
#3  apache::thrift::transport::TSocket::openConnection (this=0xbfe69ea0, res=0xbfe69e9c) at src/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:277
```

I don't quite understand the "->" operator, but it seems like `mytransport` is pointing to a `NULL` object. Any ideas?

EDIT: If I put the code into the main class, it runs normally and gives me the error I want:

`TSocket::open() connect() <Host: localhost Port: 9090>Connection refused`

(see #1 on the stack trace). However, when I put the code into a class inside a library (that the main class uses), that's when I get the segmentation fault. So it might be some sort of scope issue?

Comment: That's not what I would get from that call stack.  You can check the validity of the pointer held my `mytransport` simply by using a conditional (`if(mytransport)` { // it's ok...}`.

Comment: thanks, I tried that but I'm still getting a segmentation fault. Any ideas what might be the real cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the stacktrace and after doing some research on the code for the `TSocket.cpp`, [line 182](https://github.com/twitter/thrift/blob/master/lib/cpp/src/transport/TSocket.cpp#L182) shows the exact same error message on the `openConnection()` method. `errno_copy` get its value from `errno` that has the value `111`. According to [this](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno), that value corresponds to `ECONNREFUSED`. So I would check the connection on the other end.

Comment: I know the error is from the connection, I didn't start the server on purpose. The problem is I'm getting a segmentation fault error message, instead of the usual "Connection refused" error

Comment: So, is the `open()` call wrapping some other library that is throwing an exception?

Comment: I looked at the TSocket.cpp code and found on line 182 `GlobalOutput.perror("error message goes here")`, but GlobalOutput hadn't been initialized yet, causing the error. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!